# Using CURL to call WebRequest

Tags: c#, curl

Good day,

Been trying to call an API using CURL. The CURL is below. How can i pass the {BVN} inside?

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve_bvn/{BVN}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer SECRET_KEY'
```

The conversion of the CURL is as given below but i have issues passing the BVN parameter inside.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{ using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), 
"https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve_bvn/{BVN}"))
{
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer SECRET_KEY"); 

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the input is coming from, but you can do

```
string.format ("https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve_bvn/{0}", BVN);
```

and the code for the string BVN will go into {0}